# How can I pass TimePickerDialog value to countdown timer in android

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-timepicker

How can I pass `TimePickerDialog` value to countDown timer?
Here is my countdown timer code:

```
public class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
        long sec = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        String t = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", sec / 3600,(sec % 3600) / 60, (sec % 60));
        t1.setText("Remaining time:---"+t);
    }   
}
```

And my time picker output is 3:23 PM. How can I pass this time to countdown timer? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried to convert time to millis but output is not proper.

Comment: please show how you had parsed this to milliseconds..

Comment: String dt_time = "4/9/2016"+" "+"3:17 PM";
                        SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
                        try
                        {
                            Date date = format.parse(dt_time);
                            milliseconds = date.getTime();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }

Answer (score 0):

Like you have described in your comment, You try to `parse` a date like this:

```
String dt_time = "4/9/2016"+" "+"3:17 PM";
```

with a `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

So you get an exception. To parse a `date` like your date `String`, you need this `SimpleDateFormat`

```
"d/M/yyyy h:mm a"
```

or you have to change your date string to:

```
"04/09/2016"+" "+"03:17 PM";
```

You are using a one numbered format for Your day, month and hour in your string, but try to `parse` it with a double numbered format. I noticed that the API from `SimpleDateFormat` has changed the description. The meaning is the same, but I think the old API description was better to understand. Look here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

### EDIT

Your code should be something like this:

```
String dt_time = "4/9/2016"+" "+"3:17 PM"; 
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy h:mm a");
Date date = format.parse(dt_time);
long millis = date.getTime();

MyCountDown mMyCountDown = new MyCountDown(millis,1000);
mMyCountDown.start();
```

### EDIT 2

So now another assumption: The user selects some time in the future, let´s say 5:00 PM, and now it´s 4:00 PM. Then you have to get the current time like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long currentMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then you have the millis from your timepicker in my example above. These are in the future. then you need to substract the current time from these millis:

```
long millisToCount = millis - currentMillis;
```

Then pass this to the timer:

```
 MyCountDown mMyCountDown = new MyCountDown(millisToCount,1000);
 mMyCountDown.start();
```

Then the timer should count down until the selected time is coming up. Is that what you want?

Comment: sorry i cannot understand . can you help me how can i achieve it.

Comment: sorry output is not proper.

Comment: please be more clear....what exactly are you trying to parse? How is the string? Is it only `"3:23 PM"` or is it like in your question `"4/9/2016"+" "+"3:17 PM"` ?

Comment: see, i have a timer  user select time from it and then that time is pass to countdown timer to create countdown this is my whole task. so now i think you understand what i want to do.

Comment: So what´s the problem? My example shows what you have to do.I think you must be more clear here, I don´t get you. Just an assumption: Do you want to get some time from the timepicker to let the countdown timer count this time? Let´s say time picker is 3 hours and 40 minutes, then you want to countdown 3 hours and 40 minutes? Then you are on a wrong way, this has nothing to do with Date and PM AM....

Comment: finally i achieved it by converting time into 24hr format. thanks for support